# Where to find the Cplex library (not the GUI from AIMMS)?

Tags: java, macos, cplex

I would like to use CPLEX as a java library. However, I do not find the download site for this purpose. The google search gives a site of AIMMS, which is just GUI for the tool, if I understand correctly.

Could you help? My OS is Mac OS X , so I cannot use AIMMS's academic license. It suffices for me the cplex.jar. But I do not see where it is located... Google does not help here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2FContent%2FOptimization%2FDocumentation%2FCPLEX%2F_pubskel%2FCPLEX19.html

Here is a link for it. Unfortunely, it cannot be .jar. But if you download IBM® ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio you can found it, just follow the instructions on link.

Answer (score 0):

i figure it out myself. One should log in IBM's site. A free trial version or an academic license are available then. Cplex seems nice btw.